# AP Chem Question about Reaction Rate - Confused?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, reaction-coordinate

I found this question in the AP Chem book, and I understand why B is the answer (as the answer key says). However, I don't understand why D is not also correct.

The question is:

A multistep reaction takes place with the following elementary steps.

- Step I. A + B <-> C
- Step II. C + A -> D
- Step III. C + D -> B + E

Why would increasing the temperature make the reaction rate go up?

- (A) it is an endothermic reaction that needs an outside energy source
  to function
- (B) The various molecules in the reactions will move faster and
  collide more often
- (C) The overall activation energy of the rxn will be lowered
- (D) A higher fraction of molecules will have the same activation
  energy

I understand that B is correct based on collision theory, but why isn't D correct as well? Don't a greater % of molecules have the same activation energy at higher temperatures? (Or am I misinterpreting answer choice D?)

Thank you!

Comment: “A higher fraction of collisions will have an energy higher than the activation energy” is a correct statement. This is the main reason reaction rates increase at higher temperature. They also increase due to higher frequency of collisions. I don’t understand the statement in choice D.

Comment: If you strike out the word *same* in (D) then the statement would be true. With *same* however the statement is weird. I think *same* was thrown in to trap a careless reading of the statement.

Comment: Tangential to MaxW's point, at any temperature, all the molecules have the same activation energy, but at higher temperature more molecules will have energy in excess of that activation energy.